# Does a Java class get loaded if I access MyClass.class.getName()?

Tags: java

I want to explicitly initialize some classes during the initialization of my application using `Class.forName`, but in order make that code survive refactorings, I want to use this:

```
Class.forName(MyClass.class.getName());
```

I wonder: Wouldn't the class be loaded as soon as the `getName` method is executed thus making `Class.forName` unnecessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, even the `getName()` call is unnecessary, since in order for the `MyClass.class` object to exist, the class has to be loaded and initialized.

Of course, this method means that you have a compile-time dependency on `MyClass`, which you do not have when using `Class.forName()` with a String literal.

Comment: It isn't necessary to initialise the class - otherwise the flag in the three-argument `Class.forName` would be pointless. As it turn out, IIRC, 1.5+ do not initialise the class (uses new for of `ldc` instruction); 1.4- do initialise the class (lazily uses single-argument `Class.forName` to store in a static).

Answer (score 6):

You can easily check this out. Just add something like this:

```
static { System.out.println("Class loaded"); }
```

in the class and try it. Static blocks are executed when the class is loading.

Answer (score 3):

I just found out: `-verbose:class` shows all class loading events.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Borgwardt says, the simplest statement to achieve your aim is `MyClass.class`.

You might want to assign the value returned to something just in case the compiler ever decided that the statement had no side effects and could be optimized away, but I don't believe that any do.

Comment: But as Michael also said, using MyClass.class adds a compile-time dependency on MyClass to your code, and you might not want that. If you just use Class.forName("org.mypackage.MyClass"), then you don't have a compile-time dependency.

Comment: Well, if the OP wants to guard against refactactorings, then a compile-time dependency is exactly what he needs.

Comment: Eclipse has option: "Update textual occurrences in comments and strings" that would update class name in Class.forName statement. If he is using eclipse, that is...

Comment: If you own the code that is being refactored you probably don't have a problem having a compile-time dependency on it.